# How to make a "Khan Academy's video"

Tags: screen, capture

I am a Physics teacher. I want to make a video like Khan Academy do. I have a Wacom table and a microphone. But the problem is when I record my screen, there are too much noise and the volume level is really low. Can you suggest some softwares on Ubuntu 14.04 to solve my problem?

P/S: Sorry for my bad English!

Here is the link for Khan Academy's video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihNZlp7iUHE&list=PLAD5B880806EBE0A4

Comment: Get a better mic.

Comment: When using window 7, I have BB Flashback which can remove background noise. So what I need is a software like this. Here my window 7's resuft:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBJ46gVOzVE

BTW: thank you so much!